# Validation (by Acrobat) PDF A on linux

Tags: linux, pdf, acrobat

I'm currently using Aspose to convert documents to PDF A1 for store it into repository(http://wiki.ihe.net/index.php/Cross-Enterprise_Document_Sharing).

I must check if generated PDF are PDF A 1 compliance ( A or B, I don't care). Aspose support ask to use Acrobat Preflight to validate compliance (http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/675462/585754/showthread.aspx#585754). 
But Acrobat Preflight is'nt on Linux and others tools generates errors on validation.

Do you have any ideas to verify PDF on Linux with rules of Acrobat ?

Thanks in advance

Edit : I'm testing Vera PDF and PDF Box preflight for validation but both raises errors

Comment: One way is to use the preflight jar from [apache pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) or use online validator at [pdf-tools.com](https://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/pdfa-online-pruefen.aspx). The online validator is more strict in comparison to the pdfbox preflight.

Comment: The newest Linux Acrobat is too old for such tests. You may therefore have to look for other tools, where two have already been mentioned (the validator from PDF-Tools would be my personal favorite, as it is said to be more strict, and because PDF-Tools know what they are doing with and around PDF/A).

Comment: I've already test with PDF box preflight and Vera PDF but both raises errors :(